# How can I retrieve the value of an attribute from a xml element

Tags: html, xml, xslt, attributes

I want to know how I can retrive the url in "supervisor" to use it as a link. I have this xml file.

```
<pr>
<meta>
    <id>AAAAAAAAAAAA</id>
    <title>AAAAAAAA</title>
    <subtitle>BBBBB</subtitle>
    <bdate>OCCCCCCCC</bdate>
    <edate>DDDDDDDDDD</edate>
    <supervisor url="http://wwww.teacherwWEbpage.com">teacher NAME 
 </meta>
 </pr>
</meta>
<team>
    <student>
        <name>Rhghfghf</name>
        <nr>fghfgh5</nr>
        <email>hgghfht</email>
    </student>
</team>
<abstract>
</abstract>
<deliverables>
    <deliverable url="."></deliverable>
</deliverables>
```

And this xsl, im trying to put the XML information on a table, which is fine, but now I'm unable to set the teachers name as a link to the address in the url attribute...

How can I use that attribute as the link on the resultant HTML file?

```
</supervisor>
</meta>
<team>
    <student>
        <name>hrhshs</name>
        <nr>48648</nr>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 align="center"> Projecto Record</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="meta">
    <table>
        <tr  >
            <td width="50%"><b>name key:</b><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
            <td><b>Begin date:</b><xsl:value-of select="bdate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Title:</b><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
            <td><b>End date:</b><xsl:value-of select="edate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Subtitle:</b><xsl:value-of select="subtitle"/></td>
            <td><b>Supervisor:</b><a href="./supervisor/{@url}" ><xsl:value-of select="supervisor"/> </a></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not far off with your current attempt, but the syntax you want is this...

```
<a href="{supervisor/@url}" >
```